# Unable to install/update anything on ubuntu Server

Tags: 14.04

I'm a new Ubuntu User. I am facing issues with installing anything on the Ubuntu machine. The software/updates are just stuck at connecting. I have tried suggestions on the forum to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/913782/installing-rancid-on-ubuntu/ but technically speaking it's vice-versa. this one is more general and better formulated.

Comment: have you tried opening up "software sources" and ticking the "Cannonical Partners" then closing? (it will ask for password and the to reload the database say yes) then try running updates again?

Comment: Open a terminal and do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and update your question with the output from these two commands.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys and I apologize for the less information. As I said, I'm new and I did try researching but couldn't find a fix.
@SorenA I did try that but it is stuck at connecting and times out later. I have a working connection as other websites work fine.

Comment: @tatsu Tried Cannocial Partners but it didn't work. The link you send is not what the case it.